# How to statically access a generic subtype using type erasure in Swift?

Tags: swift, generics

Given a protocol with an associated type of `CALayer`..

```
protocol LayerQuery {
    associatedtype U:CALayer
    var id:String { get }
    var parent:CALayer { get }
    func fetch() -> U?
    ..
}
extension LayerQuery {
    func fetch() -> U? {
        return ..
    }
    ..
}
```

.. and a concrete type that specifies a subtype of the associated type, e.g. `CAShapeLayer`..

```
struct CustomBorderQuery : LayerQuery {
    typealias U = CAShapeLayer
    let id:String
    let parent:CALayer
}
```

.. with some type erasure (necessary evil) ..

```
struct AnyLayerQuery : LayerQuery {
    typealias U = CALayer
    var parent: CALayer
    var id: String
    init<Q:LayerQuery>(_ query:Q) where Q.U:CALayer {
        self.parent = query.parent
        self.id = query.id
    }
}
```

.. and a factory for generating the correct query.

```
enum Query {
    case customBorder
    case ..
    func on(_ parent:CALayer) -> AnyLayerQuery  {
        switch self {
        case .customBorder:
            return AnyLayerQuery(CustomBorderQuery(id:"..", parent:parent))
        }
    }
}
```

**How do I have this return the specific subtype for that query: `CAShapeLayer`** instead of only `CALayer`?

Example call-site:

```
if let layer = Query.customBorder.on(parentLayer).fetch() {
    // Access property "path" on CAShapeLayer:
    layer.path = UIBezierPath(..).cgPath
}
```

Ideally, I should not have to downcast (`as?`). And code completion in Xcode should provide the interface of `CAShapeLayer`.

Answer (score 1):

Your type erasure covers up the specific type of thing being constructed. That's kind of the point. You're going to have to use a downcast at some point to recover the original subtype of your query.

Comment: I see what you mean. It seems like a limitation of Swift (well, to require type erasure in the first place). This should work, but it doesn't: `struct AnyLayerQuery<U> : LayerQuery where U:CALayer`.

Comment: It is a known limitation.  See https://lists.swift.org/pipermail/swift-evolution/Week-of-Mon-20160229/011666.html (and note that this was written before Swift 3 was released.  Some of the things mentioned in the manifesto that they **hoped** to get in  Swift 3 didn't make it.

Comment: @DavidJames You'll have to give the generic placeholder a different name in order to use it with the `typealias` to satisfy the `associatedtype` – but that *should* work just fine.

Comment: @DavidJames Although that being said, I don't really understand your use of the `Query` enum – surely you'll have other cases that won't be dealing in `CAShapeLayer`s? Therefore you cannot have the `on(_:)` method returning an `AnyLayerQuery<CAShapeLayer>`. You probably just want individual static methods instead. Also it's quite well possible you don't even need a protocol here, given the only variable thing about the conforming types is the `fetch(_:)` implementation. Just a `struct` could be what you're after ([example](https://gist.github.com/hamishknight/cd80f6fd6db7f6d86cd8a2377c7e1d57))

Comment: Thanks @Hamish I agree with your suggestions (see also my comment on your gist). I suggest you provide your example as an answer to this question.